# How can I separate the years of my data in ggplot2 without adding data to my frame?

Tags: r, google-analytics, ggplot2, bar-chart

I retrieve data from google analytics with RGoogleAnalytics.
The data I get have the form

```
   year month visits
1  2011    11    106
2  2011    12    118
3  2012    01    273
4  2012    02    354
5  2012    03    353
6  2012    04    302
....
```

When I use the following statement I do not get separated bars for the data. Just a bunch of bars which add up the single years. I would want them to be separated.

```
ggplot(ga.data,aes(x=month,y=visits),group=year,colour=as.factor(year))+
+  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: Please study `?geom_bar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to group bars by `year` you could consider to use faceting for that.

```
ggplot(ga.data,aes(x=as.factor(month),y=visits,fill=as.factor(year)))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+facet_grid(~year,scale="free_x",space="free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: They most likely want `position_dodge`.